# jQuery find and select parent of element by text BUT NOT CONTAINS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<position><Identity>5</Identity></position>
<position><Identity>8</Identity></position>
let Identity = $(this).find("Identity").text(); //this equal 5
let wIdent = $(wBody).find("Position").children("Identity").text() == Identity;
```

How can I select "Position", if I have many element with name "Position", but any position have unique "Identity", for example its identity now equal to 5.

I cant use "contains" because I dont need select "55" or "85" or "15", I need select only "5"

Comment: I don't think you really mean [tag:jq], do you? That doesn't look like jq at all. You mean [tag:jquery]?

Comment: Alex, please elaborate your question in brief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $pos5 = $("position").filter(function(){ 
  return $(this).find("Identity").text() == "5"; 
});
```